# Is there any window event for orientation change using @HostListener like we have @HostListener("window:scroll", ['$event']) for scrolling?

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to detect orientation change, to detect I am viewing my application in portrait mode or in landscape mode.So is there any event like orientation change which I can pass inside hostlistener in my component to detect orientation change?

P.S - Some guys are saying it duplicate question.I don't want plain java script way, I wanted the angular way to detect orientation change.

Comment: `window:resize`?

Comment: I specifically need event for @HostListener for orientation change

Comment: If you are using Angular then I suggest you should use the official Angular CDK. What you need is the Layout Module. https://material.angular.io/cdk/layout/overview

Comment: @SplitterAlex - the guy doesn't need to pull in the entirety of Angular CDK for a native browser event...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[From MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/orientationchange_event#Example); you can use `window:orientationchange` to detect when the orientation of the device has changed.

```js
@HostListener('window:orientationchange', ['$event'])
onOrientationChange(event) {
  console.log('orientationChanged');
}
```

Here is a short clip to see this in action in Chrome Dev Tools: https://streamable.com/o2ilm

Comment: wondeful event  , but this one only support on mobile  according  to mdn I think window:resize will be better

Comment: I fail to see how orientation could apply to a desktop?

Comment: you can use the chrome dev tool  to test it

Comment: @malbarmawi - he's specifically asking for orientation detection... not resizing. Chome dev tools allows you to simulate a device and change orientation for testing as well.

Comment: @AndrewHill I used the same but not working.Yes I am asking for orientation detection.I have used the below lines of code but not working                                @HostListener('window:orientationChange', ['$event'])
  onorientationchange(event) {
    console.log("orientationChanged");
  }

Comment: @AndrewHill but this will not work in case of desktop that why I think about resize may work better but yes you are correct resize will not give the information about orientation

Comment: Answer has been updated with a video showing orientation change working in the browser. See https://streamable.com/o2ilm

Comment: Thanks @AndrewHill I actually implemented the correct event.I just didn't knew how I can trigger the event on browser. It worked like a charms!